# Pausing pywinauto loop and start over?

Tags: python, listener, pywinauto, pynput

I m trying to run python scripts when I use other applications such as MS Excel

I have a script (macro) and it runs when i hit "Caps Lock", it writes 1000times "1234". I am **only** able to **terminate** all script after writing 1000times "1234" with pressing "Esc"

Script:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import pywinauto as pw

def on_press(key):
    if key==Key.caps_lock:
        for i in range(1,1000):
            pw.keyboard.send_keys("1234",pause=0.01)
            
def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
            on_press=on_press,
            on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

How can I make it pause (the loop) when during xxth times writing "1234" and start over ? But i dont want to terminate all script. just a pause, start-over, pause and start over.....

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Note: I didn't try this code, and there is very high probability that it will not work.
That's because I just upgraded your script to give you an idea.
Listener() will probably not allow you to continue with the listening until the on_press() is over. You should see whether the Listener() class offers you the unblocking mode where it continues to listen while starting your event in an thread.
I didn't use pyinput for some time now so I do not know.
If it does or doesn't, use my model to control your thread which will do the actual writing. You start a thread which waits until a flag is True, than writes until the flag is False and so on. You use another flag to interrupt your writing loop completely, when you want to end the program in the middle of writing or wherever.
Your thread needs to have a while loop (e.g. while running: ...) which would start your for loop, which will have checks inside for paused and running flags. If paused you wait, if running is False, you break. Before your for loop you set one wait for a flag e.g. begin or you just always start with the paused = True, your choice. on_press() and on_release() just set the flags to appropriate values. I advise you to always set them in on_release(), especially if in the future you start working with mouse position and/or mouse buttons. That, however, is your preference and demand of the script's purpose and usage.
Ow, One extra thing. Do not forget to end your thread gracefully upon your script's exit. You can use atexit module to register a handler for that which would set the running flag to False and wait for the thread's termination. To indicate this you can use extra flag, I usually call it "done", which is False untill the while loop in a thread ends.
Here is an example which will work if Listener() has unblocking mode and you set it up.

```
from time import sleep

paused = False

def wait ():
    while paused:
        try:
            sleep(0.001)
        except:
            # If signal interrupts the sleep()
            break

def on_press(key):
    global paused
    if paused:
        paused = False
        return
    if key==Key.caps_lock:
        # Note: your script wrote 999 times "1024", not 1000 .
        # range() starts at first arg, and ends at second-1.
        # Your script started at 1, and ended at 999, therefore start with 0, or use range(1, 1001)
        # Or just use 1000, like I did, which is the same
        for i in range(1000):
            pw.keyboard.send_keys("1234",pause=0.01)
            wait()            

def on_release(key):
    global paused
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False
    if key==Key.<some_key>:
        # Switch paused from True to False and from False to True
        paused = not paused
```

Comment: first of all, really appreciate for respond but i couldn't do it :(  please correct me if i am wrong, just before writing "1234", I need something interruption in order to pause the loop. the scheme should be like this;
CapsLock hit --> enter loop --> check for pause --> write "1234" -->enter loop--> check for pause ... --> loop ends if i dont pause, which i am not able to:) 

just need to put something to pause